# VBA: If statement doesn't work

Tags: vba, if-statement

I have no clue, why the statement doesn't work. No error occurs but at the same time there is no result in the sheet.

```
 Sub won()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastrow As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data imput")
    lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 3 To lastrow
        If ws.Cells(i, 6) = "customer" Then
        ws.Cells(i, 16) = 1
        End If
    Next i

    MsgBox "done!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Perhaps it's working in that it evaluates to `False`?

Comment: Hi, may be a silly answer, but is "customer" written correctly,

Comment: It doesn't show False too.

Comment: Everything is written correctly, I've checked also on different columns and this code just shows no result.

Comment: working at my end.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on the line and examine the content of ws.Cells(i, 6) ... or add a Debug.Print ">" & ws.Cells(i, 6) & "<"   Maybe it's Null?

Answer (score 0):

This might be because you are searching the lastrow within Column 1.  Do it for column 6 like this:

```
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 6).End(xlUp).Row
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to define variable i.

```
Dim i As Integer
```

To prevent this error in the future put the following line of code at the top of your macro

```
Option Explicit
```

Comment: Declaring `i` variable as `Long` could be better considering an `Integer` is 16 bits and is between -32,768 and 32,768, and a `Long` is 32 bits and is between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,648

Comment: True, Long would be better since you have already declared lastrow as Long.